# WP7 stopped sync' with Exchange 2003 due to date error

Tags: exchange-2003, synchronization, windows-sbs-2003, mobile-devices

I have a WP7 device and since I first had it, I have instantly been able to sync with 2x different Exchange servers, each running from a completely seperate domain (i.e. different businesses entirely).

Now, only one works, as the other constantly gives me the following error:

> Outlook error
>
> Not updated
>
> Update the date and time on your phone
>   and try connecting again.
>
> Last tried 3 seconds ago
>
> Error code: 80072F05

I have followed all advice in terms of the date and time on my WP7, but it's not that, as the other Exchange account works fantastically well, leading me to believe that it's the server on the failing Exchange account.

The server appears fine - I can access webmail externally, or via Outlook on a PC internally as I always have done. The date and time on that server doesn't appear to be very much 'out' either.

Any thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927465/en-us) Microsoft knowledge-base article points to a certificate problem.

If you browse to OWA using the web browser *on your device* do you get an error? Or a certificate prompt of any kind? If so then resolve that and see if that resolves your EAS issue too.

Comment: I have this problem and the most infuriating thing is that my colleagues with IOS and Android phones can still use email and calendar as normal - even though the certificate has expired - but I can't do the same with my WP7 phone. An "I understand the risks" button would be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

WP7 sync error 80072F05: The SSL certificate of your Exchange server had expired.
So, renew your cert (or get your admins to do that) and you'll be fine.

And, btw, 80072EFD means "the issuer of the certificate is unknown".

Answer (score 1):

Use UTC Universal Hour Coordenate in your phone configurations. That will resolve the sync problem.

regards.